# "Alt + Tab" to switch to the previous view composed by two windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm looking for a simple way (e. g. a shortcut) to switch from current view to the previous one. In this context I cannot use the shortcut Alt+Tab because "the previous view" is composed by two windows (a window on the left side and a window on the right side).

[image]

Comment: You can try to use virtual desktops and switch between them using WIN+CTRL+RIGHT/LEFT ARROW. See [https://www.howtogeek.com/197625/how-to-use-virtual-desktops-in-windows-10/](https://www.howtogeek.com/197625/how-to-use-virtual-desktops-in-windows-10/) and [https://www.howtogeek.com/688608/keyboard-shortcuts-for-using-virtual-desktops-on-windows-10/](https://www.howtogeek.com/688608/keyboard-shortcuts-for-using-virtual-desktops-on-windows-10/)

Comment: Hello @Lluser thank you very much for your precious help. I can use also four fingers to switch between virtual desktops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Windows 10 Virtual Desktops.

Virtual desktops could be managed from Task View. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> or use an icon [image]

A new desktop is created using a button in Task View or via shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

You can arrange windows on each desktop and switch between them from Task view, or use keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+  <kbd>←</kbd>   or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+  <kbd>→</kbd>

Active desktop should be closed using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>